# /usr/bin/env deleted now sh files (scripts) and programs are not opening / working

Tags: linux, ubuntu

`/usr/bin/env` file deleted and `/bin/env` is also unlinked. I tried various techniques to recover, but they didn't work. I tried to reinstall coreUtils but got this error.

```
akash@akash:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    **Reinstallation of coreutils is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.**
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried to remove manually, but I got this error

```
akash@akash:~$ sudo apt-get remove coreutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 colord : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
 fontconfig : Depends: fontconfig-config but it is not going to be installed
 libfontconfig1 : Depends: fontconfig-config (= 2.11.94-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk2.0-0 : Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libgtk2.0-bin but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5feedback5 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntugestures5 : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-window2 : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

due to this some programs and sh (scripts) are not working.

```
akash@akash:~$ scala
    bash: /usr/local/bin/scala: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: fix your repositories

Comment: i dont know how to do that can you tell me and further more rnv file no exists

Comment: it would be easier to reinstall the whole system.

Comment: thats not an option right now i am developer hope you understand

Comment: Please Dont downVote if you dont know

Comment: If it's just `env` you've accidentally deleted, download and extract the `.deb` manually, on another machine if neccessary, and copy this one binary back.

Comment: Do you have the file `/var/cache/apt/archives/coreutils*.db`? If so you should be able to use `dpkg` to install it. In general `dpkg` is a low level tool for handling `.deb` files. If you need to go lower then a `.deb` file is just an `ar` file with 2 tar files and a marker file inside it. The `data.tar.xz` will have the `usr/bin/env` inside it.

Comment: Unfortunately `apt-get remove coreutils` is a pretty silly thing to try. There's a reason this package is called _core utilities_. Fortunately it looks like you weren't able to remove it.

Comment: @AkashSethi Downvotes have nothing to do with not knowing an answer, hover above the down arrow to see possible reasons.

Comment: Sorry didn't wanna hurt anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download the coreutils package directly from [ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com). For Xenial use [this site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coreutils).

For Debian you have to use the equivalent package search pages.